# Find first and last Row Index No for a gridview in each paging?

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview, gridviewrow

Hi i have a gridview contains hundred of records, it is having paging, every page have size 10. now i want to find the first & last row index numbers of the gridview in each paging event? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't page number times page size give you the last index on the page? `MyGrid.PageIndex + 1 * MyGrid.PageSize`
For the first on the page you could just subtract page size from the last index that you calculated